# Type of ternary expression

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, cout

Can anyone explain the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int test = 0;
   cout << "First  character " << '1' << endl;
   cout << "Second character " << (test ? 3 : '1') << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
First  character 1
Second character 49

But both the `printf` statements should print the same line.

Comment: It is a good question, but unrelated to side-effects.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The type of the expression `'1'` is `char`.

The type of the expression `(test ? 3 : '1')` is at least `int` (or an unsigned version thereof; portably it is `std::common_type_t<int, char>`).

Therefore the two invocations of the `<<` operator select different overloads: The former prints the character as is, the latter formats the integer as its decimal string representation. (The integral value of the character `'1'` is defined by your base character set.)

Answer (score 5):

`cout` will display value of `(test ? 3 : '1')` expression after deducing appropriate `<<operator`. In this case it is `int`, you can check it using nice trick that Scott Meyers propagated in his [newest book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996):

```
template < typename T > class TD; // Type Displayer
int main()
{
  int test = 0;
  TD<decltype((test ? 3 : '1'))> xType; 

  return 0;
}
```

this generates error, which will also give you information of type of your expression:

> main.cpp:6:34: error: aggregate 'TD<**int**> xType' has incomplete type and 
>   cannot be defined
>      TD xType;

which is `int`. And `static_cast<int>('1')` is 49.

Comment: `static_cast<int>('1')` is 49 on many systems, but it is not required. There are systems where it is not.

Comment: IIIRC, string literals / chars are not required to be in ASCII format unless you specify the format (e.g. `u8`). There should be a question about that too.