# What are the side effects and return type in ternary operator in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 

int test = 0; 

cout << "First  character " << '1' << endl; 

cout << "Second character " << (test ? 3 : '1') << endl; 

 return 0; 
}
```

This program expected output is

First  character 1

Second character 1

but  output is

First  character 1

Second character 49

I found this on geeksforgeeks while reading the ternary operation. but I did not understand the concept of side effect and return type the way it is explained there, please can anyone clear the concept in a simple way?

Comment: [Also see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30018841/1275169).

Comment: There are no side effects for the ternary operator (unless you put them there yourself) so don't worry about that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result-type of [the conditional (or ternary) operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) is the *common* type of both branches. In your case it's `int` (because `char` can be implicitly be converted to `int` easily, but not always the other way around). If there isn't any common type then it's an error.

You get `49` because it happens to be your systems encoded value for `'1'` (ASCII).